# Making snake game a score counter and increase movement speed

Tags: c#

so i made this simple snake game i made with a guide for as a school project now i want to improve it by adding a score counter and increase the movement speed of the snake every time you get the food help is appreciated
this is the problem i'm currently having 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPLY6.jpg)

```
namespace Snake
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WindowHeight = 32;
            Console.WindowWidth = 64;
            int screenwidth = Console.WindowWidth;
            int screenheight = Console.WindowHeight;
            Random randomnummer = new Random();
            int emtiaz = 5;
            int bakht = 0;
            pixel gz = new pixel();
            gz.xpos = screenwidth / 2;
            gz.ypos = screenheight / 2;
            gz.rangsafe = ConsoleColor.Red;
            string movement = "RIGHT";
            List<int> xposlijf = new List<int>();
            List<int> yposlijf = new List<int>();
            int berryx = randomnummer.Next(0, screenwidth);
            int berryy = randomnummer.Next(0, screenheight);
            DateTime tijd = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime tijd2 = DateTime.Now;
            string buttonpressed = "no";
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                if (gz.xpos == screenwidth - 1 || gz.xpos == 0 || gz.ypos == screenheight - 1 || gz.ypos == 0)
                {
                    bakht = 1;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < screenwidth; i++)
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(i, 0);
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < screenwidth; i++)
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(i, screenheight - 1);
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < screenheight; i++)
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, i);
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < screenheight; i++)
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(screenwidth - 1, i);
                    Console.Write("v");
                }
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                if (berryx == gz.xpos && berryy == gz.ypos)
                {
                    emtiaz++;
                    berryx = randomnummer.Next(1, screenwidth - 2);
                    berryy = randomnummer.Next(1, screenheight - 2);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < xposlijf.Count(); i++)
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(xposlijf[i], yposlijf[i]);
                    Console.Write("*");
                    if (xposlijf[i] == gz.xpos && yposlijf[i] == gz.ypos)
                    {
                        bakht = 1;
                    }
                }
                if (bakht == 1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                Console.SetCursorPosition(gz.xpos, gz.ypos);
                Console.ForegroundColor = gz.rangsafe;
                Console.Write("*");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(berryx, berryy);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
                Console.Write("*");
                tijd = DateTime.Now;
                buttonpressed = "no";
                while (true)
                {
                    tijd2 = DateTime.Now;
                    if (tijd2.Subtract(tijd).TotalMilliseconds > 500) { break; }
                    if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                    {
                        ConsoleKeyInfo toets = Console.ReadKey(true);
                        if (toets.Key.Equals(ConsoleKey.UpArrow) && movement != "DOWN" && buttonpressed == "no")
                        {
                            movement = "UP";
                            buttonpressed = "yes";
                        }
                        if (toets.Key.Equals(ConsoleKey.DownArrow) && movement != "UP" && buttonpressed == "no")
                        {
                            movement = "DOWN";
                            buttonpressed = "yes";
                        }
                        if (toets.Key.Equals(ConsoleKey.LeftArrow) && movement != "RIGHT" && buttonpressed == "no")
                        {
                            movement = "LEFT";
                            buttonpressed = "yes";
                        }
                        if (toets.Key.Equals(ConsoleKey.RightArrow) && movement != "LEFT" && buttonpressed == "no")
                        {
                            movement = "RIGHT";
                            buttonpressed = "yes";
                        }
                    }
                }
                xposlijf.Add(gz.xpos);
                yposlijf.Add(gz.ypos);
                switch (movement)
                {
                    case "UP":
                        gz.ypos--;
                        break;
                    case "DOWN":
                        gz.ypos++;
                        break;
                    case "LEFT":
                        gz.xpos--;
                        break;
                    case "RIGHT":
                        gz.xpos++;
                        break;
                }
                if (xposlijf.Count() > emtiaz)
                {
                    xposlijf.RemoveAt(0);
                    yposlijf.RemoveAt(0);
                }
            }
            Console.SetCursorPosition(screenwidth / 5, screenheight / 2);
            Console.WriteLine("bazi ra bakhti, emtiaz: " + emtiaz);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(screenwidth / 5, screenheight / 2 + 1);
        }
        class pixel
        {
            public int xpos { get; set; }
            public int ypos { get; set; }
            public ConsoleColor rangsafe { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: And what is your problem? SO is for specific questions on specific problems, not for general help on how to do this or this.

Comment: it doesn't have any problem i just want to improve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at the following 2 pieces of code

```
if (tijd2.Subtract(tijd).TotalMilliseconds > 500)
```

make a variable and use that instead of 500
Than use that variable in the following block

```
if (berryx == gz.xpos && berryy == gz.ypos)
{
  emtiaz++;
  berryx = randomnummer.Next(1, screenwidth - 2);
  berryy = randomnummer.Next(1, screenheight - 2);
}
```

and test and make changes and see how your game behaves, it will guide you to what you are trying to do.
Your variable emtiaz is already counting number of times snake gets food

Comment: using variable instead of 500 worked but score counter shows up outside of the game area

Comment: you need to determine coordinates within your game area(if thats where you want to print the counter) then just print emtiaz at those coords...
Take a look at following code and try to understand what is going on there. Thats all you need to do to print the score..

                Console.SetCursorPosition(berryx, berryy);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
                Console.Write("*");